# Doctrine2 Join Native query with different tables

Tags: php, mysql, join, doctrine-orm

Hello everybody, I'm stuck with a Doctrine join query.

The system continues telling me that Auction is not mapped:

```
Class Auction does not exist and could not be loaded in Doctrine/doctrine-orm/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/RuntimeReflectionService.php on line 40
```

The project is already on, obviously, and also other joins were used with success.

```
include_once '../../../bootstrap_doctrine.php';

$rsm = new \Doctrine\ORM\Query\ResultSetMapping;
$rsm->addEntityResult('Auction', 'Au');
$rsm->addEntityResult('VariantPerAuction', 'Vpa');

$Q=" SELECT Au.id
FROM Auction Au
JOIN VariantPerAuction Vpa ";
        $query = $entityManager->createNativeQuery($Q,$rsm);

$auctions = $query->getResult();
```

Comment: If you simply get the `Auction` repository and try find it by its id, it works? (i.e. `$repo->find($id)`)

Comment: It could works too, but I need the join clause as the query is more complicated than this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Marco Pivetta, it now seems to work.

The problem seems to be that Doctrine2 Class weren't fully namespaced.

A fast trial fully namespacing them works.

On top of each class:

```
// put the folder where your class is
 namespace DbClasses\entities;
```

The new Join Query becomes:

```
$rsm = new \Doctrine\ORM\Query\ResultSetMapping;
$rsm->addEntityResult('DbClasses\entities\Auction', 'Au');
$rsm->addEntityResult('DbClasses\entities\VariantPerAuction', 'Vpa');

$Q=" SELECT Au.id
FROM Auction Au
JOIN VariantPerAuction Vpa 
Where Au.piattaforma='EbayDE' AND Au.OggettoEbayDBContainer_id=159";

$auctions = $query->getResult();
```